# how to use crossfilter and dc.js to draw a cumulative distribution function lineChart

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter, cdf

suppose I have some records like this:

```
// origin: http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/
var livingThings = crossfilter([
  // Fact data.
  { name: “Rusty”,  type: “human”, legs: 2 },
  { name: “Alex”,   type: “human”, legs: 2 },
  { name: “Lassie”, type: “dog”,   legs: 4 },
  { name: “Spot”,   type: “dog”,   legs: 4 },
  { name: “Polly”,  type: “bird”,  legs: 2 },
  { name: “Fiona”,  type: “plant”, legs: 0 }
]);
```

Let's say I want to draw a simple CDF based on the legs variable using crossfilter and dc.js's lineChart.

The expected chart points would be:

```
x:0 --> y:0.16667
x:2 --> y:0.66667
x:4 --> y:1
```

But I don't know how can I implement this. Could you please help to do  this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand why you would want to do this, as that usually has a lot to do with the "how". Can you explain that?

Comment: Sure. The reason is that I want to use crossfilter and dc.js to draw CDF for some data that I am working with. So that I can apply any filter just by clicking on the pie, row or bubble chart.

Comment: There are 2 ways you can do this: either take Crossfilter's group output and calculate the CDF, then chart it, or construct your group, dimension, and data so that it returns a CDF instead of another aggregation. The first way is going to be more efficient but it won't work great with dc.js. When I'm back online in a couple days, I'll try to give a real answer if no one else has.